# How to transform non-json by Flink streaming

Tags: java, json, apache-flink, amazon-kinesis

How can I transform data from kinesis?

I need to **extract** "logBody" as json format from non-json format event.
In "logBody" schema will be changed dynamically. So, I just want to save as file.

Here is my event to transform:

```
["log_LogName",
  {"streamKey":"KinesisDataStream","txNo":0,"partitionKey":"123456789949","streamName":"bucketlog","qid":-1858829953885061086},
  {"tag1":null,"repair":false,"publishTime":"1619417687000","code":"act","slot":1612340400000,"tag2":null,
        "logBody":
            {"log1":"aaaaa, 0",
            "log2":"type1",
            "log3":"none",
            "log4":1,
            "log5":999,
            "log6":"000000000000001",
            "log7":"none",
            "log8":-1,
            "log9":"add",
            "log10":1612340607134
            },
         "split":18,
         "appId":"1",
         "logId":"176ddc71-65f9-11eb-bf73-29aec924521a",
         "marketOrderId":null,
         "maxSplit":56,
         "playerId":"000000000000001"
    }
]
```

I want to extract as this format

```
{
"log1":"aaaaa, 0",
"log2":"type1",
"log3":"none",
"log4":1,
"log5":999,
"log6":"000000000000001",
"log7":"none",
"log8":-1,
"log9":"add",
"log10":1612340607134
}
```

Comment: Where is your concrete problem? You consume the events as Strings I would guess parse the json with your faviourite json parser and pick what you need ... Can you please explain what you have so far and where are you struggling?

Comment: 1. Create a deserializer for that data format
2. Create a datastream that uses your deserializer
3. Transform it with some of the available functions. I recommend using your IDE autocomplete to figure out the possibilities since Flink docs aren't the best out there. proccess() for example. Then you can look them up online.
As Tobi said, your problem is very vague. Starting out with Flink can be annoying, but it'll all start making more sense with time and you gotta get your hands on it for it.